# Android:how to set tag with spinner item

Tags: android, android-spinner

Is it possible to set tag with spinner item.I want to set my bean object as tag with each spinner item is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May this help you:

Create your Own CustomAdapter as shown Below and add tag in `getView()` Method of that..

**CustomAdapter:**

```
public class MySpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

    private Activity context;

    public MySpinnerAdapter (Activity context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        RelativeLayout item= (RelativeLayout)context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.<your spinner item layout name>, null); 

      //set your data to layout components

      item.setTag(<your tag object>);

        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this the only way?can't we do this with array adapter

Comment: @Agr1909 its customAdapter buddy.. like we customise the array adapter according to our requirement..

Answer (score 1):

Use Custom Adapter And set the **view.setTag(yourObject);**